# Firebase Domain Hosting is slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

How long does it take to verify the domain?
Also I got message:

> Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience, it usually takes less than an hour. This is with the assumption that the TXT records you've placed in your DNS were right. Then after verification, you need to wait for the SSL certificate to be provisioned. (which is around 24 to 48 hours).

The message that you got is an indication that your TXT records were not verified yet

Quoting from firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain):

For the TXT verificaion:

> Depending on your domain provider, this verification step may be
>   instant or it may take an hour or more.

For the SSL Certificate provisioning

> Once domain ownership is verified we will provision an SSL certificate for your domain and deploy it across our global CDN. This process can take 24 - 48 hours.

Comment: I just answered your question :)